# Show PlacePicker location on Google Map

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase-realtime-database, google-places-api, geofire

I am using google map for showing two different locations. First one is cooker location which i am getting from firebase-databse using geofire getlocation. Second location is current user which i want to get from placepicker and then show on map.

But unfortunately after select location from placepicker i get only cooker location on map. How can i show both location on map?

That's relevant code.

```
   private GoogleMap mMap;
SharedPreferences mPrefrences;

DatabaseReference locationRefrence = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Expert Location Information");
GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(locationRefrence);

Button btnConfirmLocation;
private int PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST=999;

LatLng userLocation;

String placeName,placeAddress;

Boolean flag = false;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps_for_cooker);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    mPrefrences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor =  mPrefrences.edit();


    btnConfirmLocation = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnConfirmLocation);

    PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();

    try {
        Intent intent = builder.build(MapsActivityForCooker.this);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST){
        if (requestCode == RESULT_OK){

            Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data,this);
            placeName = String.format("Place: %s", place.getName());
            placeAddress = String.format("Address: %s", place.getAddress());
            userLocation = new LatLng(place.getLatLng().latitude,place.getLatLng().longitude);

            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(userLocation)
                    .title(placeName).snippet(placeAddress)
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA)));

            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(userLocation,11));

            flag = true;

        }
    }
}
@Override
public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    final Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(80, 80, conf);
    Canvas canvas1 = new Canvas(bmp);
    Paint color = new Paint();
    canvas1.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.cooker), 0,0, color);

    String location = mPrefrences.getString(getString(R.string.COOKER_ID)," ");


    geoFire.getLocation(location, new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(String key, GeoLocation location) {

            LatLng cookerLocation = new LatLng(location.latitude,location.longitude);

            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(cookerLocation)
                    .title("Cooker Location")
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmp)));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(cookerLocation));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15),2000,null);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    if(flag == true){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"User location",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(userLocation)
                .title(placeName).snippet(placeAddress)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA)));

        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(userLocation,11));
    }


    btnConfirmLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MapsActivityForCooker.this,User_sign.class));
        }
    });

}
```